# Google App Engine, how to set custom response headers

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using the `node` runtime and flexible environment.

I would like to set custom HTTP response headers at the web server level (nginx). They should be present when testing the app before deployment.

Is this possible on GAE?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set custom response headers in App Engine Flex with node.js you have to set it in the code.

Example: `response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');`

[Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/v10.5.0/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value) for reference.

Comment: Thank you, this I can do but I wanted to affect the headers set by Nginx.